# "Mit all seiner Kraft" or "Mit aller seiner Kraft"? Which one is correct?

Tags: grammar, preposition

***Mit aller seiner Kraft zog er den schweren Stein hinterher.***

With all his might he pulled the heavy rock behind him.

***Mit all seiner Kraft hob er das Gewicht über seinem Brust auf und machte 3 Sätze von 15 Wiederholungen.***

With all his strengh he lifted the weight over his chest and did 3 sets of 15.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's 'all seiner' or 'aller Kraft'. But never 'aller seiner'.

> Mit aller <s>seiner</s> Kraft zog er den schweren Stein hinter **sich** her.
>
> Mit all seiner Kraft hob er das Gewicht über seine<s>m</s> Brust <s>auf</s> und machte 3 Sätze **mit jeweils** 15 Wiederholungen.

Comment: OT: Um ausdrücklich darauf hinzuweisen, dass er das "Gewicht _auf_hob", also "von ganz Unten hoch holte" ginge auch noch: "*... hob er das Gewicht auf, über seine Brust und machte ...*"

Comment: Ich würde hier nicht "sets" mit "Sätze" übersetzen, offensichtlich ein "false friend", der nur beim Tennis funktioniert, und auch "3 Sätze mit jeweils 15 Wiederholungen" kann so nicht stimmen. Ich bin kein Gewichtheber, mit "3 sets of 15" dürfte aber eher "3 von 15 Durchgängen" oder etwas Ähnliches gemeint sein, eventuell kann man auch "Sets" lassen, falls das im Kontext gebräuchlich ist. Wenn es nicht gerade um Tennis geht, wird in einem physischen Kontext unter "Satz" ein Sprung verstanden.